# Creating an intent chooser from an Android Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a GCM Service that I want to create an Intent chooser (with `Intent.createChooser()`), but despite various things I've been trying I always get `Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?` Am I doing something wrong or cna you just not do this from a Service?

The service's code is below (there are some comments in there from various things I've tried);

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService 
{
    // ...

    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = "Push received";
        displayMessage(context, message);
        fireIntent(context, message);
    }

    private void fireIntent(Context context, String url)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share URL"));
        //context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share URL"));
        //sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, starting an `Activity` from a `Service` is not a good idea, since `Service` is running in background while some other applications can be in foreground. Popping an `Intent` chooser while some other app is running will completely break the user experience. A good decision is to use clickable `Notifications` to let user start the `Activity` himself when he wants it. Hope this helps.